# PHP - How to Hide Ajax Directory When Requesting it in Javascript File in a MVC Project?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm writing a MVC project. I have two directories. First one is public. Everybody can reach this directory. It contains index, javascripts, css etc... Second one contains application files. This directory is forbidden from normal users, and ajax files are contained here(in the controllers folder). When I use ajax php files in javascript, I have to use something like "application/controllers/ajax/file.php". The problem is, I don't want to expose my directory. I want to hide it like "ajax/file.php". What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use mvc server side too (but a php one like symfony, laravel, etc.) or at least make a routing system in your `ajax/file.php` then you ajax call will hide the real path of the file which will do operations.

Comment: How can I implement the route system in the ajax file?

Comment: you could do a basic routing with a substring of ``$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`` and doing some pattern matching

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATE:** You can create a function in controller and you can use route.

```
class A {
  function ajax() {
    // return data
  }
}
```

Use route and call it as `http://example.com/A/ajax`
I hope you got it.

Comment: How to use a route?

Comment: ı'm using Core PHP.

Comment: how your page routing is?